# Calling a compose UI function (displaying snackbar) from a normal activity that is not extending ComposeActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

- I am trying to launch a compose function that I have in an Object class and trying to call in Normal activity rather than
  compose activity
- I am actually trying to build a VDS (UI library) in compose but I am trying to use it in normal activity. Things like popping SnackBar etc.

**MainActivity1.kt**

```
class MainActivity1 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1)

        TestingCall()
    }
}
```

**TestingObject.kt**

```
object TestingObject {
    @Composable
    public fun TestingCall() {
       // Some UI that pops up 
    }
}
```

**Error::**

```
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
```

[image]

Comment: You can Only call `Composable` from a another `Composable` function thats what the error says. you should call it like `setContent {
            TestingCall()
        }` if u want to use Compose .

Comment: @ADM ... I posted above sample to simplify .... I am actually trying to build a VDS (UI library) in copose but ... I am trying to use it in normal activity .... Things like popping snackbar etc ....

Comment: In order to do that you have to have a Composable scope to call your Compose method. I don't think Directly calling method will work . Check https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis it might help . And Edit your question with little bit with what u are trying to achieve with this . i will try to Reopen it .

Comment: @ADM  ... I have edited question title and body for clarity .... please check if it can be reopened

Answer (score 0):

To call a composable function inside an activity, you have to call [setContent](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#(androidx.activity.ComponentActivity).setContent(androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionContext,kotlin.Function0)) first inside your onCreate:

```
class MainActivity1 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1) //

        setContent {
            TestingCall()
        }
    }
}
```

Since you're using Jetpack Compose for the UI, there is no need to assign a layout. So you can remove the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1)`.

Comment: Hey Devrath. Have you checked my solution above?